# Firebase DB: If I place observer on posts, will ALL nested posts be returned any time there is a change to a single one?

Tags: swift, firebase-realtime-database

Say as user has posts nested under him, and any time any of that user's posts changes we need to let him know.  I placed an observer on user/posts, but my concern is via the docs I believe this results in ALL posts being returned every time a single one is changed.  Is this indeed the case or is only the changed post coming over the network?

```
ref.child("users/\(currentUserId)/posts").observe(FIRDataEventType.value, with: {[weak weakSelf = self](snapshot) in
        weakSelf?.allpostModel.hasFetched = true
        if let fetchedPosts = snapshot.value as? [String : [String : Any]]{
            weakSelf?.allPostsModel.postsJSON = fetchedPosts
        }
    })
```

If I am correct and the user must pay for data for ALL posts to come over the network any time a single post changes in this implementation, what then would be a better solution?  Place an observer on every post, and make a dictionary in my posts model with postIDs as keys for easy updating?

Answer (score 0):

The Firebase Database client will try to minimize the amount of data that is synchronizes. There may be some overhead, but in general if will do a pretty good job of not retrieving data it already has.

But your code will still have to figure out what the changes are. You'll have a much easier time if you respond to child events, such as `.childAdded`, `.childRemoved` and `.childChanged`. If you respond to those events, you can easily perform the minimum update to the UI too.